# Implicit Function Theorem Confusion

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to understand the Implicit Function Theorem. I thought that the IFT states that within a certain neighborhood $U$, we can find some function $g : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ for a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ s.t. the function $f$ stays in the zero locus, i.e. $f(x,g(x)) = 0$.

First of all, is what I said above correct/okay? It's basically saying there exists some function s.t. our function $f$ remains in the zero locus (or some locus)?

I don't really understand how the IFT can be used for the first example found in this link: http://www.math.pitt.edu/~sph/1540/1540-notes7.pdf It asks us to solve the equations in terms of $u,v$ in a certain neighborhood. I don't really see how we can use the IFT which is due to not really understanding the IFT itself too well.

Can someone first explain the theorem and then tell me why we can use it for the example in the provided link?

Comment: Could You please write out the example or at least give the size of the notes? I do not want to download possibly several megabytes for just half a page.

Comment: @LutzL It's 5 pages.

Comment: Thanks. That is reasonable. So first of all, your initial description of the theorem is correct. Now the question is where your stumbling block is. Is it that $x$ and $y$ are multi-dimensional vectors? Or is it that you have to perform variable name translation from $((x,y),(u,v))$ to $((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))$?

Comment: @LutzL It's that I don't really see how the question/problem fits inside the the theorem. I thought we would use the theorem to show there exists some function $g(x)$ so that our $F(x)$ stays in the zero locus. We are asked to solve for $u$ and $v$ though.. how does it fit in the theorem?

Comment: In the example, you are looking for a local solution $(u,v)=g(x,y)$ for the equation $F(x,y,g(x,y))=F(x,y,u(x,y),v(x,y))=0$. Seems the problem really is that in the example, $y$ is used as the second free variable and $u$ and $v$ as the dependent variables.

Comment: This is not the statement of IFT. There are a lot of things missing. For example, there is a deteminant clause associated with $f$, and the function $g$ is a unique continuous function staisfying this in a sufficiently small neighborhood.